# How to slice and summarize tensor matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

How to slice and sum the tensor matrix. I have a matrix like this:

```
[[0.   0.   0.   0.12 0.75 0.13 0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.06 0.89 0.05 0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.3  0.39 0.31 0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.18 0.63 0.19 0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.09 0.03 0.89]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.14 0.7  0.16 0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.12 0.02 0.86]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.1  0.02 0.88]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.03 0.93 0.04 0.   0.   0.  ]
 [ 0.06 0.89 0.05 0.   0.   0.  0.   0.   0.  ]], shape=(10, 9), dtype=float64)
```

As a result, I want to remove all zeros and get a matrix like this:

```
[[0.12 0.75 0.13]
 [0.06 0.89 0.05]
 [0.3  0.39 0.31]
 [0.18 0.63 0.19]
 [0.09 0.03 0.89]
 [0.14 0.7  0.16]
 [0.12 0.02 0.86]
 [0.1  0.02 0.88]
 [0.03 0.93 0.04]
 [0.06 0.89 0.05]], shape=(10, 3), dtype=float64)
```

I think I should slice the input matrix into three parts shape=(10,3) and summarize them tf.math.add(tf.math.add(tf.slice(x, [0, 0], [-1, 3]), tf.slice(x, [0, 3], [-1, 3])),
tf.slice(x, [0, 6], [-1, 3]
Thx for you advices

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = [[0., 0., 0., 0.12, 0.75, 0.13, 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0.06, 0.89, 0.05, 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0.3, 0.39, 0.31, 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0.18, 0.63, 0.19, 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.09, 0.03, 0.89],
     [0., 0., 0., 0.14, 0.7, 0.16, 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.12, 0.02, 0.86],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.1, 0.02, 0.88],
     [0., 0., 0., 0.03, 0.93, 0.04, 0., 0., 0.],
     [0.06, 0.89, 0.05, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]

tf.reshape(tf.gather_nd(x, tf.where(tf.not_equal(x, 0))), (-1, 3))
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(10, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.12, 0.75, 0.13],
       [0.06, 0.89, 0.05],
       [0.3 , 0.39, 0.31],
       [0.18, 0.63, 0.19],
       [0.09, 0.03, 0.89],
       [0.14, 0.7 , 0.16],
       [0.12, 0.02, 0.86],
       [0.1 , 0.02, 0.88],
       [0.03, 0.93, 0.04],
       [0.06, 0.89, 0.05]], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: You will get the error if the will be 0 in other parts of matrix for example 0.12, 0., 0.13

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow 2.x

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.convert_to_tensor(
    [[0., 0., 0., 0.12, 0.75, 0.13, 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0.06, 0.89, 0.05, 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0.3, 0.39, 0.31, 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0.18, 0.63, 0.19, 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.09, 0.03, 0.89],
     [0., 0., 0., 0.14, 0.7, 0.16, 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.12, 0.02, 0.86],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.1, 0.02, 0.88],
     [0., 0., 0., 0.03, 0.93, 0.04, 0., 0., 0.],
     [0.06, 0.89, 0.05, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]
     )


res = tf.reshape(x[(x!=0)], (-1,3))
```

If you have variable number of positive numbers on each row.

```
x_ragged = tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(x)
mask_ragged = tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(x!=0)

res = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(x_ragged, mask_ragged)
```

PS: The second solution results in small differences in numbers (e.g. 0.12 becomes 0.199999) (probably a datatype issue). You probably can fix that by forcing f32 or f64 data type. I haven't investigated that.